# Retrofit Error - Response must include generic type (e.g., Response<String>)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Response must include generic type (e.g., Response<String>)`

I am getting this error while calling api using retrofit. This started happening when I migrated to Android Studio Flamingo and update the AGP version to 8.0. In previous AGP & android version API calling was working perfectly fine.

This is happening only in release build and things are working fine in debug build.

**API Call Code**

```
fun getIpApiData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        ipApiLiveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            if (AppUtility.hasInternetConnection()) {
                AppUtility.showProdLog("INSIDE IP API")
                val response = repository.getIpApiJson(AppConstants.IP_API_FIELDS)
                ipApiLiveData.postValue(handleIpApiResponse(response))
                AppUtility.showProdLog("IP API SUCCESS")
            } else {
                ipApiLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(app.getString(R.string.internet_connection), AppConstants.ERROR_CODES.APP_ERROR_CODE))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            AppUtility.showProdLog("EXCEPTION IP API - $e")
            AppUtility.showProdLog("EXCEPTION IP API - ${e.message}")
            val errorMsg = handleException(e)
            ipApiLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(errorMsg, AppConstants.ERROR_CODES.APP_ERROR_CODE))
        }
    }


suspend fun getIpApiJson(fields: String) =
        RetrofitInstance.buildServiceWithURL(IGToolsAPI::class.java, IP_API_BASE_URL).getIpApiJson(fields)

@GET("json")
    suspend fun getIpApiJson(@Query("fields") fields: String): Response<IpApiJson>
```

The code goes in the catch block showing this exception - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Response must include generic type (e.g., Response<String>)`

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type



# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters. InnerClasses is required to use Signature and
# EnclosingMethod is required to use InnerClasses.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod

# Retrofit does reflection on method and parameter annotations.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations

# Keep annotation default values (e.g., retrofit2.http.Field.encoded).
-keepattributes AnnotationDefault

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*

# With R8 full mode, it sees no subtypes of Retrofit interfaces since they are created with a Proxy
# and replaces all potential values with null. Explicitly keeping the interfaces prevents this.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>

# Keep inherited services.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface * extends <1>

# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation

# R8 full mode strips generic signatures from return types if not kept.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* public *** *(...); }
-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class <3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that it only happens in the release build only the following comes to the top of my mind, hope it helps:

Check ProGuard/R8 Configuration: If you are using ProGuard or R8 for code obfuscation and minification, check your configuration files (`proguard-rules.pro` or `consumer-proguard-rules.pro`) to ensure that the necessary Retrofit-related classes, annotations, and models are not being obfuscated or removed. You may need to add specific rules to keep the necessary classes and annotations intact.

If you've confirmed that ProGuard/R8 is the cause of the issue, you can try adding specific rules to keep the necessary Retrofit-related classes intact. Here's an example of a ProGuard rule for Retrofit:

```
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep interface retrofit2.** { *; }
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Recommended proguard configurations can be found at https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro - Retrofit's official repository.